# Undefined in associative array lookup

Tags: javascript

```
var candidates = {           
  "1":"Barack Obama",
  "2":"Mitt Romney",
  "3":"Dennis Kucinich",
  "4":"Quentin Tarantino",
  "5":"Count Dracula"
};



    function getRandomInt(min, max){
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};

function getRandomPresident(){
  var num = getRandomInt(1, Object.size(candidates));
  if (num!=5){

    alert(num);
    var key = num.toString();
    var res = candidates[key];

    return res;



  } else {

        getRandomPresident();

  }

   }


 alert(getRandomPresident());
```

This code works, but sometimes after generating random value it outputs "undefined" instead of the name - http://jsbin.com/uriwal/edit#source    Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying again (the `else` block), you don't return the new value. You should pass the return value through:

```
return getRandomPresident();
```

Currently, you're picking a new item, but as the function doesn't return it, the return value is `undefined`.

Comment: but why exactly the second return?? i thought i could just invoke the routine and it will return if it got the proper value..

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: Perhaps this simplified example helps: http://jsfiddle.net/8QTC9/. If you remove one `return`, then the "chain" is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the getRandomInt() function can return 0, which your associative array does not have. Just create a tighter check in the if clause:

```
if (num >= 1 && num <= 5) {
    // do stuff
}
```

EDIT:
Scratch that, you have getRandomInt(1, max). In any case, why even have a recursive function? Just do this:

```
var num = 0;
while ((num = getRandomInt(1, ...)) > 5) {
    num = getRandomInt(1, ...);
}
```

// return the resource
Hope this helps

Comment: `getRandomInt` can't return 0 because of the final `+ min`

Answer (score 0):

Change function to this:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```